# Cleaning non-disposable objects correctly

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, idisposable

Short question on how to use the `Dispose Pattern` completely correctly.
I am disposing managed resources in my Dispose-method.

But, what about **objects** which are **not disposable**?
Like `String` or `System.Text.Decoder` or...

How do i handle these objects correctly. What happens if i don't set them to `null` an if i don't let the GC finalize them `GC.SupressFinalize(this);`?

Here is an example of how do I implemented the Pattern:

```
  private class RequestState : IDisposable {
    const int BufferSize = 1024;
    public StringBuilder RequestData;
    public byte[] BufferRead;
    public WebRequest Request;
    public Stream ResponseStream;
    // Create Decoder for appropriate enconding type.
    public Decoder StreamDecode = Encoding.UTF8.GetDecoder();
    public MyMamespace.Machine Machine;

  public RequestState() {
    BufferRead = new byte[BufferSize];
    RequestData = new StringBuilder(String.Empty);
    Request = null;
    ResponseStream = null;
  }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  #region IDisposable
  private bool disposed = false;

  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
  }

  #region IDisposable
  private bool disposed = false;

  public void Dispose() {
    Dispose(true);
    // GC.SupressFinalize(this);         // What happens if I tell the GC that this object is alredy finalized??
  }

  protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) {
    if ( !this.disposed ) {
      if ( disposing ) {
        // Dispose managed resources.
        ResponseStream.Dispose();
        Machine = null;                 // Do I need this?
      }
      // release unmanaged ressources

      disposed = true;
    }
  }

  ~RequestState() {
    Dispose(false);
  }
  #endregion
}
#endregion
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface

Comment: @Steve, Thanks I was looking for an article like this. This brought more light into my confusion of cleaning resources in .Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If they don't implement the disposable pattern then the authors of those classes are saying "these things don't need any special cleaning up".

And you don't need to assign `null` either - the whole point of the GC is that it finds the stuff that's no longer used - you don't need to try to "help it" (and many efforts, if they have any effect at all, actually hinder the GC)

You shouldn't ever call [`GC.SupressFinalize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.suppressfinalize.aspx) on any object where you're not the author of its class<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>And now I'm waiting for a comment that points out some edge case that I don't currently have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to explicitly set references to `null`, but doing so will allow those instances to be garbage collected even if your instance continues to be referenced after it is disposed.

My personal opinion is that setting references to `null` when that reference is no longer need is a good practice as it helps locate bugs.

If you implement the Disposable pattern and your object has a finalizer, you should always call `GC.SuppressFinalize()` on the instance within your `Dispose` method. Doing so informs the runtime that it does not need to call the instance's finalizer, as the instance has already been disposed.

Calling `GC.SupressFinalize()` will not cause the garbage collector to "miss" instances that may be collected.